# How do I use the .NET Core Options Pattern with envorinment variables that contain periods?

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I have a .NET Core console application setup with all the packages to use the Options pattern. Settings coming from my `appsettings.json` work just fine, but my environment variables contain period characters like:

```
App.Setting.Value1 = "someval"
App.Setting.Val2 = "somethingelse"
```

I am trying to strongly type my settings using the Options pattern, but C# property names can't have period characters in them.

How do I configure during DI init time for this?

Answer (score 1):

use custom attribute binder:

```
  public class MySetting{
       [ConfigurationKeyName(Name="App.Settings.Value1")]
       public string Value1{get;set;}
       [ConfigurationKeyName(Name="App.Settings.Value2")]
       public string Value2{get;set;}
    }
```

source: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36010

Comment: I would add that it was added in .NET 6 which was released at the end of 2021, which is more than an year from the original question.